# Comprobar que existan diccionarios anidados en orden y mostrar una ruta especifica, Python

Tags: python

Python, no encuentro un tutorial que me ayude con esto, el objetivo es comprobar que los diccionarios anidados de C en este caso, coincidan con lo que se ha ingresado en un input, que exactamente es C D F G, ensima otro problema, mostrarlo en su orden en una cadena de texto. ¨

// Con esto se crea el diccionario del ejemplo //

```
sobre_ti={}
def aprender(oraciones):

    recordar_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():

        if palabra not in recordar_pal:
            recordar_pal[palabra] = {}

        recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]

aprender(input("Escribe: A A A A"))
aprender(input("Escribe: B C D F"))
aprender(input("Escribe: D E F G"))
aprender(input("Escribe: C D F G"))
print(sobre_ti)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del que hable

```
def componer(oraciones):
    ver_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra in ver_pal.keys():
            print("Verdadero")
        else:
            print("Falso")
        ver_pal = ver_pal[palabra]

componer(input("Dile algo: "))
print(mostrar)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). ¿Qué has hecho? ¿Nos puedes compartir el código que tengas o una idea de cómo atacar el problema?

Comment: Por favor, proporciona un [mcve] que reproduzca el punto en el que estás, incluyendo un conjunto de datos de ejemplo. Tal y como lo planteas, no solo pides que lo hagamos **para ti**; ni siquiera aclaras exactamente lo que quieres. Te sugiero consultar [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: @Juanjo lo unico que tengo es un sencillo diccionario como el del la imagen y un input, pero lo añadire.

Comment: @Juanjo Listo, eso es lo que tengo.

Comment: Por definición, los diccionarios en python no garantizan ningún orden. Si quieres mantener un orden, tendrás que usar una lista de diccionarios o una clase especializada llamada `OrderedDict`. Pero intuyo que lo que preguntas es el modo de _"encadenar"_ diccionarios de modo que "C D F G" extienda "B C D F". ¿Es así?

Comment: Me temo que no se entiende. ¿Qué deben almacenar los diccionarios resultantes? ¿Qué iría en la clave y qué en el contenido? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo habría de quedar el diccionario final (aparte de la figura en la que lo que se ve parecen más bien listas) Por otro lado, ¿por qué estás usando diccionarios para esto? Si es importante el orden de los elementos el diccionario no es la estructura más apropiada. Podrías usar una lista en la que vas guardando cada input del usuario, convertido a su vez en una lista. ¿Te serviría una solución así?

Comment: @ChemaCortes Los diccionarios solo son diccionarios dentro de diccionarios, el codigo garantiza que se guarde en un orden como lo siguiente, si ingresas A B C D, Como A existe no crea un diccionario A sino que añade a B dentro de A y dentro de B añade C y dentro de C añade D, entonces el objetivo del input es que si ingresas ejemplo A A A A un mecanismo se encargue de encontrar en el diccionario esa misma ruta, comprobando que exista y luego la muestre como una cadena en pantalla A A A A existe.

Comment: @abulafia Los diccionarios solo son diccionarios dentro de diccionarios, diccionarios es lo que habra en las claves y en los valores, el codigo garantiza que se guarde en un orden como lo siguiente, si ingresas A B C D, Como A existe no crea un diccionario A sino que añade a B dentro de A y dentro de B añade C y dentro de C añade D, entonces el objetivo del input es que si ingresas ejemplo A A A A un mecanismo se encargue de encontrar en el diccionario esa misma ruta, comprobando que exista y luego la muestre como una cadena en pantalla A A A A existe.

Comment: Un momento! Creo que lo he entendido. El código que has puesto al inicio de tu pregunta no es lo que has intentado para responder a la pregunta. ¡Es la pregunta! Te han dado ese código y al ejecutarlo sale la estructura de diccionarios anidados que se muestra en la figura. Y se te pide que, una vez creada esa estructura, escribas código que verifique si la secuencia "C D F G" aparece en ella, mediante una especie de búsqueda en profundidad. Si esto es así, básicamente veo que nos has pegado el enunciado de un ejercicio y nos pides que lo hagamos por tí.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas requieren que muestres antes tus propios intentos. SOes no es un lugar para pedir que te hagan la tarea, sino para responder dudas concretas puntuales. Te puedo dar una pista sobre por dónde atacar el problema. Empieza por asegurarte de que comprendes correctamente la función `aprender()`, pues un mecanismo muy similar te permitirá construir la función `comprobar()` que necesitas.

Comment: @abulafia No, tanto el diagrama de ejemplo como el código es de mi autoría, es parte de lo que hay que realizar, pido ayuda porque no se como continuar lo que me falta, osea la parte de comprobar no se como realizarla, estoy estancada, el diagrama lo cree en app.diagrams.net para que usted vean el ejemplo mas visual, realmente no es una tarea es algo que no se como continuar.

Comment: @abulafia habia añadido el codigo en tu respuesta por error, asi que lo mude a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que aparentemente se trata de parte de una tarea académica, y es política del sitio no resolver este tipo de cuestiones, te daré algunas explicaciones e indicaciones para que intentes resolverlo por tí misma a ver hasta dónde llegas. Si no consigues resolverlo del todo al menos llegarás a un punto en el que puedas mostrar el código con lo que hayas intentado y plantear una pregunta concreta que encaje mejor con el uso del sitio.

## Estructura de datos a crear

Has proporcionado un diagrama para ayudar a comprender el problema. Sin embargo creo que puede ser más claro todavía (sobre todo a un público programador) que muestres el diccionario resultante, que contiene la estructura de datos que habrá que manejar. Ese diccionario es el que sale en el `print(sobre_ti)` del código de la pregunta, y es como sigue (lo formateo un poco para que se lea mejor):

```
{
 'A' : {'A': {'A': {'A': {}}}},
 'B' : {'C': {'D': {'F': {}}}},
 'D' : {'E': {'F': {'G': {}}}},
 'C' : {'D': {'F': {'G': {}}}}
}
```

Aqui vemos que la estructura completa es un diccionario cuyas claves son la primera letra introducida por el usuario, y los valores son más diccionarios anidados, hasta llegar finalmente a un diccionario vacío.

Si recorres cualquiera de las ramas, por ejemplo la correspondiente a la clave `'C'`, las claves que vamos encontrando (D, F, G) corresponden a las letras introducidas por el usuario.

En este sentido sí hay un "orden". Aunque los diccionarios python no garantizan el orden de sus claves (es decir, el diccionario "principal" tiene cuatro claves pero las podemos encontrar en el orden A, B, C, D o A, C, D, B, o cualquier otro), una vez eliges una de sus claves, el resto de diccionarios que se van encontrando tienen ya una sola clave, y el orden en que vamos avanzando en la estructura, cada vez más adentro, sería el orden al que te refieres en la pregunta.

## Cómo se ha creado esa estructura

Esto lo hace la función `aprender()` y es interesante pararse a entenderla, pues es la clave para que implementes después otras funciones como la que verifica si una secuencia dada como "C D F G" está almacenada en la estructura.

```
sobre_ti={}
def aprender(oraciones):
    recordar_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra not in recordar_pal:
            recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
        recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
```

Una línea importante es `recordar_pal = sobre_ti`. Esto no hace una copia del diccionario `sobre_ti`, sino que hace que la variable `recordar_pal` y la variable `sobre_ti` se refieran **ambas** al mismo diccionario (inicialmente vacío).

Después se van recorriendo las letras que el usuario haya introducido. Supongamos que ha introducido "C D E F". La primera sería la C.

- `if palabra not in recordar_pal` mira si la C está en el diccionario `recordar_pal`. Ya que hemos visto que este diccionario es el mismo que `sobre_ti` y que está inicialmente vacío, será cierto que la "C" no está, por lo que se ejecutará:
- `recordar_pal[palabra] = {}`. Ahora el diccionario `recordar_pal` tiene ya una entrada y por tanto vale `{ 'C': {} }`.  Recordemos además que `sobre_ti` *es el mismo diccionario*, por tanto ya hemos añadido una clave "de primer nivel" a la estructura de datos deseada.
- Y ahora viene otra línea fundamental: `recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]`. Esto hace que la variable `recordar_pal` ya no se refiera al diccionario `sobre_ti`, sino al diccionario interno (vacío en este momento) que está asociado a la clave `'C'`.

Al iterar a la letra siguiente "D", todo se repetirá, pero teniendo en cuenta que ahora `recordar_pal` es el diccionario vacío interno. Por tanto cuando se mire a ver si contiene una "D" se verá que no está, y cuando se añada se añadirá a ese diccionario interno, con lo que `sobre_ti` pasará a valer `{ 'C': { 'D' : {} }` y se prepara `recordar_pal` para que se refiera al nuevo diccionario vacío interno.

De ese modo se construye la estructura anidada.

## ¿Cómo verificar si una secuencia está en el diccionario?

Y llegamos a la tarea que tienes que resolver. La idea es usar una variable auxiliar como la `recordar_pal` que se usaba en `aprender()` que comience apuntando al diccionario "total" (`sobre_ti`) y que en un bucle verifique si la primera letra dada está en ese diccionario. Si no lo está ya se puede retornar `False` indicando que no está. Si sí que está, entonces se reasigna esa variable auxiliar para que apunte al diccionario interno, y se repite el bucle.

Si agotamos todas las letras dadas y no hemos retornado aún False, entonces es que todas estaban. En ese caso se retorna `True`.

## Como "imprimir en orden"

Esta tarea no está claramente definida. Dices que hay que ir imprimiendo "en orden", y supongo que te refieres al orden de anidamiento. Pero no está claro si quieres imprimir sólo la rama que se está comprobando (lo que sería tan simple como ir imprimiendo las letras a medida que las verificas), o si necesitas imprimir el árbol entero. En el segundo caso podrías usar recursividad, pero quizás se trata de un concepto que aún no conozcas. En todo caso no queda claro si el diccionario interno puede contener ramificaciones (por ejemplo si al crearlo se usó la cadena "A A A A" y después "A A B B", en cuyo caso el diccionario tendría esto:

```
{'A': {'A': {'A': {'A': {}},
       'B': {'B': {}}}
       }
}
```

Si tal estructura fuera posible ¿cómo debería ser el resultado de "imprimirla en orden"? ¿Debería salir como resultado "AAAA" "AABB"?

---

## Ampliación

El/la usuario/a ha añadido el siguiente código como prueba de lo que intenta hacer:

```
def componer(oraciones):
    ver_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra in ver_pal.keys():
            print("Verdadero")
        else:
            print("Falso")
        ver_pal = ver_pal[palabra]

componer(input("Dile algo: "))
print(mostrar)
```

Esto es muy cercano ya a lo que se pedía, pero la lógica está al revés. No se trata de comprobar si una letra está entre las claves y entonces poner "Verdadero" (pues "Verdadero" debería significar que *todas* las letras han sido encontradas en orden). Sin embargo sí es correcto que si una letra no se encuentra se puede decir "Falso", pues basta que una falle.

Por tanto la lógica sería: Verificar si una letra está entre las claves. Si no está, ya podemos retornar `False` (es mejor retornar resultados que imprimirlos, para que la función sea más útil). Pero si está, no podemos aún retornar `True`, necesitamos seguir comprobando las letras siguientes. Solo si *hemos agotado* ya todas las letras podremos retornar `True`, pues ese caso sólo ocurrirá si no se había retornado antes `False` y por tanto es el caso en que todas las letras han sido encontradas.

Por tanto:

```
def componer(oraciones):
  ver_pal = sobre_ti
  for palabra in oraciones.split():
    if palabra not in ver_palabras: 
      return False             # Basta que una no esté para retornar False
    ver_pal = ver_pal[palabra]
  return True                  # Solo si agotamos el bucle están todas

ejemplo = input("Dile algo: ")
print(componer(ejemplo))
```

## Solución a "imprimir en orden"

Esta puede ser más compleja debido a que pueden existir bifurcaciones en el grafo, como la que se mostró anteriormente tras el usuario haber introducido "A A A A" y después "A A B B".

Creo que la implementación más simple (en el sentido de que el código es muy breve, pero no en el sentido de que sea fácil de comprender) es hacer una función recursiva.

Una función recursiva es una que se llama a sí misma para completar el trabajo. La forma de pensar sobre ellas es "¿Y si tuviera una función que supiera imprimir el árbol desde uno de sus nodos intermedios hacia abajo? ¿Cómo podría hacer uso de esa función para imprimir el árbol entero?" Entonces programas suponiendo que esa función existe, y razonas de la forma siguiente:

- Si el árbol que tenemos que imprimir está vacío, es un caso más simple que debería tener solución inmediata.
- Si el árbol no está vacío, ¿podemos juntar de algún modo lo que contiene el nodo actual más lo que haría esa hipotética función que sabe imprimir el resto del árbol?

Y la magia de la recursividad es que esa hipotética función será precisamente la que estamos escribiendo, que se llamará a sí misma.

La recursividad es un concepto difícil de entender, y también es difícil ver cómo funciona aún si tienes delante la solución. Te ofrezco una posible implementación, pero quizás sean posibles otras. Esta es la que se me ha ocurrido.

La idea es que a la función se le pasa un árbol y una cadena. El árbol debe entenderse como un "sub-árbol" (es decir, todo lo que hay desde uno de sus nodos intermedios hacia abajo). Puede contener ramificaciones. La cadena, que denominaré "prefijo", contiene los nombres de todos los nodos desde la raíz hasta el nodo que es el subárbol.

Por ejemplo considera esta estructura:

```
{
 'A' : {'A': {'A': {'A': {}}}},
 'B' : {'C': {'D': {'F': {}}}},
 'D' : {'E': {'F': {'G': {}}}},
 'C' : {'D': {'F': {'G': {}}}}
}
```

E imagina que queremos imprimir en la rama "D" el subárbol que tiene por clave "E", es decir, un sub-árbol que contiene `{'F': {'G': {}}}`. Entonces la función que estamos a punto de escribir recibiría como árbol a mostrar `{'F': {'G': {}}}` y como cadena prefijo `"DE"` (pues hemos llegado a ese sub-árbol atravesando primero "D" y luego "E").

¿Qué debería hacer la función con esos datos si pudiéramos hacer uso de otra que es capaz de imprimir un sub-árbol si le pasamos ese sub-árbol y un prefjo? Pues llamaría a esa función pasándole un sub-árbol más pequeño (`{'G': {}}`) y un prefijo más largo: "DEF". Y esta es la llamada recursiva a sí misma.

El caso trivial, cuando el árbol que llega está vacío, es imprimir simplemente la cadena-prefijo.

Basta de preámbulos, esta es la implementación:

```
def imprime(arbol, prefijo=""):
  if arbol == {}:
    print(prefijo)
  else:
    for clave in arbol:
      imprime(arbol[clave], prefijo+clave)   # <--- recursividad
```

Como ves la función se llama a sí misma sin hacer ningún print. Deja que la función invocada sea quien haga ese print. El print ocurrirá cuando se haya alcanzado el final de una rama, el diccionario vacío. Entonces se imprimirá el "prefijo" que contendrá las claves de todos los diccionarios por los que se ha ido pasando.

Veamos si funciona. Primero preparamos un ejemplo:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("A A A A")
aprender("B C D F")
aprender("A A B B")
print(sobre_ti)
```

---

```
{'A': {'A': {'A': {'A': {}}, 
       'B': {'B': {}}}}, 
 'B': {'C': {'D': {'F': {}}}}
}
```

Tenemos un caso con una bifurcación. Llamamos a nuestra función (observa que en la primera llamada no le pasamos prefijo, por lo que éste tomará el valor por defecto `""`, lo que es perfecto pues no hemos recorrido aún ningún nodo cuando queremos imprimir desde la raíz)

```
imprime(sobre_ti)
```

Salida:

```
AAAA
AABB
BCDF
```

Funcionó! Para entender cómo ha funcionado te recomiendo que uses un depurador y ejecutes paso a paso la función, examinando qué recibe como parámetro cada vez en el `arbol` y en el `prefijo`, para que puedas comprender la recursividad.

Comment: No es un trabajo académico realmente, para armar ese codigo tuve que mirar muchos videos, soy nueva en python lo mas simple se me puede complicar, tu explicación es muy buena es exactamente lo que hace, sobre la pregunta que hiciste el resultado a imprimir sería exactamente el que se ingreso ejemplo A A A A descartando otras ramificaciones como A A B B, gracias por tu ayuda, tratare de hacer lo que me explicas por mi cuenta, me tomare un tiempo intentando descifrar como hacerlo, otra ves gracias.

Comment: Intente crear esto pero lanza error a la hora de encontrar una letra que no existe, sin embargo tampoco tengo idea de cómo imprimir la ruta, he intentado de múltiples formas y esta es la que parece funcionar un poco.

Comment: `def componer(oraciones):
    ver_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra in ver_pal.keys():
            print("Verdadero")
        else:
            print("Falso")
        ver_pal = ver_pal[palabra]

componer(input("Dile algo: "))
print(mostrar)`             Disculpa no se como agregar el codigo correctamente en estos comentarios.

Comment: Lo siento, no sabia como hacerlo, puse el codigo en tu respuesta al final.

Comment: @Lolita No pasa nada. Ya he visto tu edición, estabas muy cerca. He ampliado la respuesta para corregir lo que tenías mal.

Comment: @Lolita Ya de paso te doy una solución (recursiva) al problema de imprimirlo. Espero que te sirva y se pueda entender.

Comment: Has hecho más de lo que esperaba, eres increible, gracias por tu ayuda en verdad, seguiré adelante con el resto, creo que con lo me explicaste puedo continuar lo demás que falta, ahora tengo que averiguar cómo cambiar un diccionario en una ruta específica, pero este tema podemos darlo por concluido, muchas gracias Abulafia.